# How can I securely pass the certificate password to signtool.exe in Inno Setup?

Tags: security, passwords, inno-setup, code-signing, signtool

How can I securely pass the password to `signtool.exe`?
Here's the code:

```
[Setup]
SignTool=mysigntool signtool.exe" sign /f <path_to_pfx_certificate> /p <certificate's_password> $f
```

I know there's a method like `GetSHA1OfString`, but here I need the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to encrypt the password, it does not make sense. An encryption needs a key (aka a password). So you end up with another password, which you again need to store somewhere in plain text. It's a kind of a chicken or the egg problem.

All you can do is to [*obfuscate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) the password.

---

Consider protecting the certificate by putting it into the Windows certificate store instead of a password-protected file. This is the same question you have, just for MSBuild: [How do I securely store a .pfx password to use in MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710357/850848) The answer is pretty much generic.  You just replace the MSBuild's `%(SignFiles.Identity)` with Inno Setup's `$f` in the `signtool` command line:

```
signtool.exe sign /sha1 <value> /t ... $f
```

---

Other related questions:

- [How do I securely configure a CI server to digitally sign binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27022632/850848)
- [Automated Code Signing - Protecting the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22431526/850848)